# Почему через сервер css работает, а при открытии на компьютере нет?

Tags: css, css3

В общем очень странная проблема. Вчера мучился, воевал с навигационным меню , чтобы она разделители ставила с помощью псевдоэлементов. Радостный и довольный решил что победил, спасибо ребятам с этого сервиса,НО тут какая та фантастика творится. При открытии с компьютера никаких разделителей нету, стиль не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии на компьютере, но с помощью Go Live который есть в Visual Studio Code - стили все работают и проставляются нужные разделители

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит, и как отобразить это на компьютере тоже, без Go Live?

на всякий случай привожу сюда весь код

```css
* {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
}

header {

    height: 67px;
    background-color: #212121;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    padding: 26px 70px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
.menu .menu_link {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  
}


.menu .menu_item::after {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 10px;
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
        width:5px;
    height: 31px;
    background-image:url('https://sun9-38.userapi.com/impf/05jcXkOYvNFsPxCgPD6XHo4FBj513YZ_DKvcGA/rzdRCo8VnyM.jpg?size=2x31&quality=96&sign=a622eac88a32cf9144e29c5d9e3b9d3b&type=album');
/*
    Выше я поставил абсолютный адрес с картинкой, чтобы тут видно было
 стили разделители, а вообще изначально стоит стиль как строчка ниже, может от этого ошибка? Здесь кстати плохо отображается картинка, вместо png в jpg переведена"

background-image:url('/img/bg/separated.png');
*/
    background-repeat: repeat-y;



}

.menu .menu_item:last-child::after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как Вам сказать  "<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> ", у меня его  нету , это stackoverflow тут так подставляет наверное

Comment: stackoverflow ничего не подставляет

Comment: @andreymal Нету у меня слэшей , вот как у меня выглядит https://sun9-61.userapi.com/impf/vgWiH1FleKVv3nGRaxlv5avR37dO4ifdn8tMQw/q19ye2MPq70.jpg?size=863x523&quality=96&sign=ae5009d99b1ab11e0df014d5f6e8dfc0&type=album